# Schedule Annotaion not running

Tags: ejb-3.1

i have the following Bean

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class RunWork {

@Schedule(minute = "*/2", hour = "*")
private void init() {
    System.out.println(new Date());
}
```

}

I also use the Glassfish Application Server as FULL-Platform.
But the Method above dosen't run every 2 minutes.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your method public.
The server would be violating the encapsulating of visibility methods. 
The JVM already does with Serializable type and the private variable this interface declare.